# Match with type phrase_prefix doesn't work when words mix numbers and letters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query as such:

```
{
   "match": {
      "query": "100",
      "fields": "description",
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
   }
}
```

However, if I search for "100" wanting to find, for example, a document with the "description" as "pipe 100mm", it doesn't bring me this document as a result, it only matches "100" as a prefix for other number (i.e. 10056) or as a full word.

I am using the Javascript client. Description is a field mapped as text.

What are the limitations of phrase_prefix on this case, and what could I change in the query so I can get the results as wanted?

My field mapping is

```
{
   "description": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
         "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
         }
      }
   },
   "analyzer": "ac_filter"
}
```

The analyzer indicated is built as

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "accent_filter": {
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
            ],
            "char_filter": [
                "alphabets_char_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
        },
        "char_filter": {
            "alphabets_char_filter": {
                "pattern": "[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]",
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "replacement": " "
            }
        }
}
```

I haven't tried to use ngrams or search_as_you_type yet as I wanted to understand why the above does not work. If there isn't a workaround, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use match_phrase_prefix

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "description": {
                "query": "100"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

response

```
{
    "took": 77,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.8025915,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_phrase",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.8025915,
                "_source": {
                    "description": "10056"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_phrase",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "zQV_KIcBceOx_UfLZ8wC",
                "_score": 0.60996956,
                "_source": {
                    "description": "pipe 100mm"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I was wrong, didn't work for me. I'll update the question with more information.

Comment: I just test your regxp with 'pipe 100mm',  it results to 'pp'. The accent_filter delete '100mm'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multi match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

Ex:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "100",
      "fields": ["fieldA", "fieldB"],
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but phrase_prefix isn't working as I intended. Therefore, this didn't help.